# Flex AdvancedDataGrid with Grouping, how do I get objects to appear under first GroupingField if the second GroupingField is null?

Tags: apache-flex, advanceddatagrid

I am using an AdvancedDataGrid with two GroupingFields. The dataProvider has a list of objects with these two field values, but occasionally the second field value can be null. When it loads, the AdvancedDataGrid UI has a root folder (first GroupingField) and some additional subfolders (second GroupingField). This is all good. However, the objects with a null value for the second GroupingField, just get placed in a subfolder with no label.

I want the objects with a null second GroupingField value to appear as leaf nodes beneath the root folder (first GroupingField) minus the blank subfolder.

A good way to picture this would be a file explorer. Is there a good way to do this? Make the folder icon disappear maybe after expanding this node through actionscript?

```
ParentFolder
   SubFolder
      Leaf Object
      Leaf Object
   SubFolder
      Leaf Object
   Leaf Object
   Leaf Object
```

Comment: ADG is a terrible and wondrous thing.

I'm still trying to figure out the "data" object structure when using group fields

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider passing hierarchical data into your ADG rather than using a GroupingCollection on flat data. With hierarchical data, nodes with children will be represented as folders, nodes without children will show as leafs (just like a Tree control behaves).

Just like this: http://www.flex-blog.com/tree-in-advanced-datagrid-example/

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the blank objects from your list of objects first(using a loop or filterfunction) and then set it as the dataprovider of the datagrid.